# Understanding Power Diodes and Heatsinks

Tags: diodes, heat, heatsink

I am working on reverse engineering and understanding a circuit board from the 1970s. I don't have a schematic diagram from the manufacturer. This board has an unmarked power diode that has a flange which is bolted to a large heatsink that is external to the casing. The diode casing is about 1/4" in diameter without the flange.

I've run a spice simulation on the circuit treating this diode as a standard diode and I get:

- Max current = 3A
- Forward voltage = 0.86V

So the power dissipation is 2.6W.

If I go to digikey and search for standard diodes that can handle 3A with a Vf of 1V I get the 1N5408RLG. This looks like a regular diode. Clearly no need for a heatsink.

https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/1n5400-d.pdf

What am I missing? Is it just old technology vs new or do I have a misunderstanding?

Thanks!

[image]

(red is current, green is voltage)

Comment: It will be running at ~150C above ambient at that current.

Comment: @DKNguyen - yes, just noticed that in the datasheet - but if it's rated for that current and that is the temp, then why isn't it in a package that uses a heatsink?

Comment: Because that's what it can handle. A bridge might be able to handle 1000 tons on it, but that doesn't mean you should actually put 1000 tons on it.

Comment: I would think with a bridge there is always a safety margin. The 1N5408 can handle a max peak of 200A before it is destroyed, so I guess 3A is the max continuous. Seems it doesn't need a heatsink then?

Comment: When I say a bridge can handle 1000 tons on it, I literally mean it can handle 1000 tons and no more. No abstractions about safety margins and such when I say 1000 tons. And yes, there are safety margins so you would design the bridge for 1000 tons but never put more than 250 or 500 tons on it. And in this case, they're telling you it can handle 3A. The datasheet says the component can tolerate 175C, and so they give you the current that makes it reach that when ambient is room temperature. So, are you going to run with no safety margin?

Comment: No, I am simply trying to understand why this component can run so hot and not be designed to use a heatsink whereas I am looking at a 1970s component bolted to a large heatsink.

Comment: They're telling you *exactly* how far you can push the component. They're not trying to tell you how to use the component in a conservative, realistic design. They're telling you the limits. 150C-175C is a fairly common maximum silicon temperature. You just usually don't ever want to run it that borderline. If I tell you somebody can deadlift 1000lbs, it doesn't mean you should have them going around lifting 1000lbs in the warehouse all day, but it does tell you exactly how much they can handle. It keeps things from getting fuzzy by tossing in safety margins and such and leaves that for you.

Comment: _"I would think with a bridge there is always a safety margin."_ - I would think so, too. 3A through a 3A diode on the other hand has zero safety margin.

Answer (score 1):

These flanged diodes could easily handle 50A or more; a Vf of 0.9V (maybe something more) is plausible. If you post the schematic maybe we'll see what it's trying to do, big axial diodes (like the P600, for example) were already in use. I don't think they put such a thing for only 3A.

Comment: I'm not sure yet what it is trying to do. If spice says the max current is 3A then why would it ever encounter more than that?

Comment: It's probable that's there some trick or that the spice modelling has some flaw. Or maybe some corner condition where it *will* suck a lot more current. Difficult to say without a schematic

Comment: OK, if I search on Digikey for a 50A diode I get RHRG5060. This has a thermal resistance of 1 deg C/W. So if I run 2.6W through it it will only be 2.6 deg C above ambient? That does not seem like much.

Comment: @Andy That's likely the junction to case thermal resistance. So it will run two degrees above the temperature of the heatsink. You need a big heatsink to reach 1 °C/W to ambient. If you are contemplating running it without a heatsink, look for the junction to ambient thermal resistance, which is bound to be tens of °C/W.

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to meet *all* the requirements. If the diode will get to 175 degrees, is that an okay temperature for the diode? If not, you have to cool it down. But no matter how good your cooling is, you still aren't allowed to use more than 3A.

(Well, you can try - it's a datasheet, not a cop - and while it might even work, all guarantees go out the window)